# how to merge two Observable by key in Rxjava?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I have a Observable a

```
class User {
    public int userId;
    public String userName;
    public int age;
    public Boolean vip;
}
```

Dataset:

```
userId  userName  age   vip
   1       ham     21  false
   2       lily    18  false
   3       potter  38  false
```

Observable b

```
class VIP {
    public int userId;
    public Boolean vip;
}
```

Dataset:

```
userId  vip
   1   true
```

the expected merge result:

```
userId  userName  age   vip
   1       ham     21  true
   2       lily    18  false
   3       potter  38  false
```

As known, Rxjava has `Merge`, `Concat`, `Zip`, `Join`, but they all seems like can't do this

Answer (score 1):

If the two streams have the same order by user then you can `zip` them:

```
users.zipWith(vips, (u,v) -> new User(u.userName, u.userId, u.age, v.vip))
```

You could modify the `u` but best to prefer immutability (so create a new object).

If the two streams have different order you can use `matchWith` from [rxjava2-extras](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava2-extras#match-matchwith).